# Effective way to add "time" dimension to two dimensional (x, y) NetCDF file, which has variables reprecenting same variable at different times

Tags: python, csv, netcdf, python-xarray, dimensions

I had CSV file with x and y coordinates, as well as variable values for three different time steps as follows:

```
x, y, var_t1, var_t2, var_t3,
1, 1, 8,      8,      6
1, 2, 6,      1,      2
2, 1, 5,      3,      7
2, 2, 7,      2,      6
```

I have learned to create a NetCDF file with the following method:

```
import xarray as xr
xr.Dataset.from_dataframe(df.set_index(['x', 'y'])).to_netcdf('filename.nc')
```

This results in a NetCDF with x and y as dimensions, and I get 3 different variables.

My goal was to create a NetCDF with x, y and t as dimensions with a single variable.

I managed to achieve this but I feel like I did it in a very complicated fashion.

My solution was to play with the CSV file and make it 3 times longer, while adding a "t" column to represent time steps:

```
x, y, t, var_t1, var_t2, var_t3,
1, 1, 0, 8,      0,      0
1, 2, 0, 6,      0,      0
2, 1, 0, 5,      0,      0
2, 2, 0, 7,      0,      0
1, 1, 1, 0,      8,      0
1, 2, 1, 0,      1,      0
2, 1, 1, 0,      3,      0
2, 2, 1, 0,      2,      0
1, 1, 2, 0,      0,      6
1, 2, 2, 0,      0,      2
2, 1, 2, 0,      0,      7
2, 2, 2, 0,      0,      6
```

Now when I apply

```
import xarray as xr
xr.Dataset.from_dataframe(df.set_index(['x', 'y', 't'])).to_netcdf('filename.nc')
```

I get a NetCDF with x, y, t dimensions and a single variable for each different time (i.e. when t = 1, only var_t2 != 0).

Would there be a way to achieve this in a much simpler way, in case I encounter a similar problem in the future? This was easy to do with only 3 time steps, but I would be in trouble with tens or thousands of time steps.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say you have the dataframe `df`:

```
>> df
x  y  var_t1  var_t2  var_t3
0  1  1       8       8       6
1  1  2       6       1       2
2  2  1       5       3       7
3  2  2       7       2       6
```

You can set x,y as an index, convert it to xarray, merge the variables var_t1... to a new dimension and set `new_times` as the coordinates of the time dimension:

```
>> ds = df.set_index(["x", "y"]).to_xarray()
>> ds
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (x: 2, y: 2)
Coordinates:
  * x        (x) int64 1 2
  * y        (y) int64 1 2
Data variables:
    var_t1   (x, y) int64 8 6 5 7
    var_t2   (x, y) int64 8 1 3 2
    var_t3   (x, y) int64 6 2 7 6


>> new_times = range(3)
>> ds_result = ds.to_array(dim="time").assign_coords(time=new_times)
>> ds_result
<xarray.DataArray (time: 3, x: 2, y: 2)>
array([[[8, 6],
        [5, 7]],

       [[8, 1],
        [3, 2]],

       [[6, 2],
        [7, 6]]])
Coordinates:
  * x        (x) int64 1 2
  * y        (y) int64 1 2
  * time     (time) int64 0 1 2
```